# R - survival: survfit.object (cumhaz = baseline or centered?)

Tags: r, survival-analysis

For a `survfit.object`, is the attribute `$cumhaz` the baseline or centered cumulative hazard?

Where:

- **baseline** = all covariates are set to zero
- **centered** = all covariates are set to mean of data

Looking at the documentation (`?suvfit.object`) is not very helpful:

```
cumhaz hazard:  optional. For a multi-state curve this is an k by k array for each time point, where k is the number of states.
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bit more [digging](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.11-4/topics/survfit), turns out you can explicitly choose centered vs. baseline when calling `survfit()`:

```
survival::survfit(a_coxph_model, centered=F)
```

Comment: The reason that centered was chosen as the default is that an estimated hazard for models involving either continuous or factor variables may be meaningless. For instance if age is entered as an uncentered variable then the "baseline hazard" will be an estimate of the hazard of a person at age 0.

Comment: Makes sense.  If I want to take advantage of the relationship `A(t) = A0(t) * exp(X*B)` (where `A0` = baseline cumhaz), I will need to calculate the baseline hazard (`h0(t)`) with covariates set to 0 (versus set to mean); correct?

Comment: That's the issue. I generally use the `predict.*` function appropriate to the class of the  model fit.

Comment: Ahh, interesting - I'll take a look at that function

Comment: The other reason to prefer the centered version is that the covariate coefficient estimates are referenced to it.